# What's the best way to add blanks between variables in an echo?

Tags: php

Let's say our `echo` looks like this

```
echo '<p> Usr1 has '. $array[1]['amount']. ' '. $array[1]['item']. ' in Slot 2 <br \>';
```

Notice the `' '` between the two arrays / variables. Is there a better looking and more optimized way to do so?

Comment: Doesn't get any better than that.

Comment: @dwhite.me Yes, best would be to of course skip it completely but your idea is a way to make it better looking.

Comment: Sidnote: Using multiple spaces (with the spacebar) will not increase the amount of spaces, but as already suggested above, using multiple `&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;` etc. will add extra spaces, if needed. I know this goes against what you want to do, am *just saying*. @Metro1337

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `printf` statement would look nicer here:

```
printf('<p>Usr1 has %d %s in Slot 2 <br />', $array[1]['amount'], $array[1]['item']);
```

I'm assuming the first var is a digit, and the second a string.

More info at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php).

Comment: I concur. I love `sprintf()` :) Also, you can use `printf()` and drop the `echo`: http://ie2.php.net/printf

Comment: You can use just `printf` without `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

That is one way of doing it.

An alternative would be:

```
echo "<p>Usr1 has {$array[1][amount]} {$array[1][item]} in Slot 2<br \>";
```

Note that the quotes surrounding the name of the item in the array are not needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use some pattern and replace values in it:

```
$phrase = '<p> Usr1 has #AMOUNT# #ITEM# in Slot 2 <br \>';
echo str_replace(
    array('#AMOUNT#', '#ITEM'), 
    array($array[1]['amount'], $array[1]['item']), 
    $phrase
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also capture your values into variables and use double-quotes to interpolate, like this:

```
$amount = $array[1]['amount'];
$item = $array[1]['item'];

echo "<p> Usr1 has $amount $item in Slot 2 <br />";
```